# get which term matched each record when looping through the records

Tags: php, mysql

One thing I cant seem to get working is to output the textarea field even if no data is found in the database.
Something like this:

Database values:

- Data1 - description image
- Data2 - description - image
- Data3 - description - image

Now if someone searches for:

- Data1
- Data2
- Data4

the output should look somehting like this:

- Name - description - image - Data1 (textarea value)
- Name - description - image - Data2 (textarea value)
- Name - description - image - Data4 (textarea value even if not found)

I hope this is somehow understandable

this is my code so far

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
          <form method="post">
          <textarea name="search" type="search" list="searchkey" placeholder="search"  class="search"></textarea>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="click" value="search"  />
<?php
      $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'skfstapel');
          if(isset($_POST['submit']))
           {
              $textarea = trim($_POST['search']);
              $search = implode("|",preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/", "",explode("\n", $textarea)));
              $_SESSION['firstname']= $textarea;
            }
                if(($_SESSION['firstname']!=""))
                {
                  $view = $db->query("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE firstname REGEXP '$search'");
                  $check = mysqli_num_rows($view);
                  if($check!=""){
                   while($output = mysqli_fetch_array($view))
                {
              ?>
          <div class="reslt">
              <?php echo $output['firstname']; ?>
              <?php echo $output['lastname']; ?>
            </h3>
          <hr>
          </div>
              <?php }  }  } else { ?>
            <p class="error">
              Error: Add new data enter and check the correct keyword
            <p>
              <?php } ?>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: `echo $output['firstname'];` <-- should be used like this in your case since $output is an *array* and not an *object*

Comment: Ah yes thanks! I edit my code like you said

Comment: No problem, good luck with the rest of your project :) @JCSama provided you the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop on the keywords not the sql results :

```
...
if($check!=""){
$output  = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($view)) {
   $output[$row->firstname] = $row;
}
$keywords = explode("\n", $textarea);
foreach($keyword as $keywords){
 if(array_keys_exists($keyword, $output){
...
```